# Can you explain how JSON objects are stored inside a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json

Here I'm iterating over JSON objects stored inside a javascript object and print some of it's values.

```
 database.ref().once("value", function (snap) {
    //store javascript object containing JSON objects in scores variable.
    scores = snap.val();

    for(var key in scores){
        console.log(scores[key].Name);
    }
});
```

[image]

scores object look like this.

[image]

How does the for loop retrieve the key in each JSON object and store in the variable named "key"?

Since scores is not an array but a javascript object how does a for loop work at all?

For example `scores[1].Name` won't work. So, it's not index based.

Comment: Might find what you're looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object).

Comment: `for..in` is specifically for looping over the keys in an object, so that's why it works. That's what it's designed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement iterates over the [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of the given object.

Asuming you have the following object:

```
var o = { 
  a: 1, 
  b: 2, 
  c: { 
    d: 3 
  } 
};
```

Doing:

```
for (var key in o) console.log(key, o[key]);
```

Will print:

```
a 1
b 2
c { d: 3 }
```

I think it is important to keep in mind that the `for...in` statement also loops through the [inherited properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) of the object.

Doing:

```
o.__proto__.x = 4;
for (var key in o) console.log(key, o[key]);
```

Will print:

```
a 1
b 2
c { d: 3 }
x 4
```

If you want to loop only through the properties that belong to the object directly, and not to the prototype chain, you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var o = { 
  a: 1, 
  b: 2, 
  c: function () {}
};

o.__proto__.x = 4;
o.__proto__.y = function () {};

var keys = Object.keys(o);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) console.log(keys[i], o[keys[i]]);
```

The code above prints:

```
a 1
b 2
c function () {} //functions are also enumerable
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain why this is not working? `console.log(scores);
console.log(scores[1]);`
https://imgur.com/a/Ry7J0

Answer (score 2):

In your example you have an object that looks like:

```
var obj = {
  'key1': {name: 'Josh', score: 9},
  'key2': {name: 'July', score: 30},
  'key3': {name: 'Joy', score: 18},
  'key4': {name: 'Barbara', score: 50},
};
```

Doing `for (var key in obj) {...}` will loop through all the **keys** of your initial object. In that example, that would be `['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']`.

You are right to say that only array items can be access by index. For objects, children are accessed by keys (which are strings).

Both the following work:

```
// Directly when you know the key name
console.log(obj.key1.name); // Will print out 'Josh' 

// Using a variable when the key name is stored in a variable
var customKey = 'key1';
console.log(obj[customKey].name); // Will print out 'Josh'
```

In your initial example, you are using the `for ... in` structure to loop through he object keys and then accessing the nested objects by key.

You can verify what I am saying with the following example:

```
database.ref().once("value", function (snap) {
    //store javascript object containing JSON objects in scores variable.
    scores = snap.val();

    for(var key in scores){
        console.log(key); // See what's inside your key variable
        console.log(scores[key].Name);
    }
});
```